# ScrollView выходит за рамки дозволенного

Tags: android-studio, android-xml

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/ScrollViewContact"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/imageChat"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textAddContact"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayoutContact"
        >

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

ScrollView смотря из кода ужат между элементами `imageChat` и `textAddContact`
При работе приложения, ScrollView выходит за рамки которые указаны следущим кодом`app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/imageChat"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textAddContact"` Почему ScrollView выходит за рамки дозволенного ей пространства?

Answer (score 0):

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:id="@+id/ScrollViewContact"
    app:layout_constraintHeight_default="wrap"
    app:layout_constraintWidth_default="spread"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/imageAddContact"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/imageChat"
    >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayoutContact"
        >
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Вопрос решился написание верного кода для контейнера ConstraintLayout в котором находится ScrollView , чтобы по высоте не выходил элемент нужно указать`hieght = 0dp` обязательно нужно добавить `app:layout_constraintHeight_default="wrap"`